# cakephp submit array to database

Tags: database, cakephp

hi all I'm trying to add information to the database using a hasMany with joins association

```
Invoice - id, sender_id, receiver_id, template_id
Field - id, name, description, default_value, template_id
fields_invoices - id, invoice_id, field_id, entered_value
```

here is the view

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('FieldsInvoice'); ?>
<?php foreach ($fields as $field): ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden($invoice_id); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden($field['Field']['id']); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->Input($field['Field']['name'], array('default' =>$field['Field']['default_value'])); ?>
<?php endforeach ;?>
<?php echo $this->Form->End('Submit');?>
```

here is the controller

```
public function create($id)
    {   
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Create Invoice');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');   
    $this->layout='home_layout';


     if (!is_numeric($id)) throw new BadMethodCallException('I need an ID');
     $this->Invoice->id = $id;
     if (!$this->Invoice->exists()) throw new NotFoundException('Invalid ID');

    $this->set('invoice_id',$id);

    $names = $this->Invoice->find('list',array(
    'fields'=>array('template_id'),
    'conditions'=>array('id'=>$id)));

    $fields = $this->Field->find('all', array(
     'conditions'=>array(
     'template_id'=>$names)));

    $this->set(compact('fields'));
    $this->set(compact('invoice_id'));

    $this->set('name',$names);
    $this->Invoice->create();
    if(empty($this->data)){
        $this->data= $this->Field->read($id);
    } 
    else{
        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            die(debug($this->data));

            $this->Invoice->create();
            if($this->FieldsInvoice->save($this->request->data, array('deep'=>true)));
            {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The field has been updated');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'invoices', 'action'=>'index'));

            }
            //else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('Could not be saved');
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

here is whats printed when debug is used

```
\app\Controller\InvoicesController.php (line 134)
array(
    'FieldsInvoice' => array(
        (int) 87 => '',
        (int) 0 => '',
        'invoiceno' => 'test1',
        (int) 99 => '',
        'duedate' => 'test2',
        (int) 999 => '',
        'amount' => 'test3',
        (int) 9999 => '',
        'description' => 'test4'
    )
)
```

all the correct information is there but not submitting to the right place, the first int is the `invoice_id`, the other other int's are `field_id` and 'test1','test2','test3','test4' are the `entered_value`. somehow I need to code my view so that it saves an `invoice_id`,`field_id,test1` in the same array, how can I acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are creating 2 hidden fields for each of the fields.

First read this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto

```
echo $form->input('Account.0.name', array('label' => 'Account name'));
echo $form->input('Account.0.username');
echo $form->input('Account.0.email');
```

And then further reading: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-hasmany-through-data

Comment: i dont want the user to touch the invoice_id or field_id

Comment: i also don't want the id to be apparent to the user

Comment: @user1393064 you do realize that they are still pretty much viewable by viewing source right?

Comment: it doesn't bother me at the moment, as long as it looks pretty. issue now is it only prints the last entered value